# VNC Virtual Display Driver

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have a server remotely hosted without a monitor attached. It is running Windows Server 2003 x64, and I am remotely connecting to it via VNC. The biggest I can make the resolution is 640x480, are there any virtual device drivers out there that can increase the resolution?

I can't use remote desktop as I need to share the session with several other comptuers. This machine is acting as a monitor for several sites, and is watched by many people.

Ideally, I'd like to be 1920x1200.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As VNC simply follows the console's screen, all you need to do is change the screen resolution to the size that you want.  This might disconnect your VNC session when you press the "Apply" button, but you'll have 15 seconds to connect back and click "Keep" so that it sticks.  I've had to deal with this before, and this is the quickest method of fixing the issue - get in, change the resolution, if you get dropped connect back, keep the settings.  Newer versions of VNC will automatically adjust the resolution for you, eliminating the annoying drop.

Comment: Without a monitor the onboard resolution only lets me go to 1024x768, and I'm looking to go much higher. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've also seen this too.  Hate to say it, but you'll need to attach the monitor, set the resolution, and then detach it.  The resolution will stay fixed after that, but for some reason, some video card drivers cap their resolution if they can't find a monitor.  It's probably an old behavior from the bad old days of when you could catch a crappy 14" monitor on fire if you overdrive it for too long, which means suddenly hooking one up would be an issue; in this day and age, it just isn't an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) which comes with a display driver that gives you more control.

Comment: I just looked at this - it only appears to be a mirror driver like RealVNC - is there someway to virtually increase resolution?

Comment: If you actually attached a monitor are you sure the graphics card would let you set it above 1024x768? If the hardware isn't capable, no virtual driver is going to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

VNC will only let you switch to the maximum resolution supported by your actual console video driver. If this is limited to 640x480, you may be using the system default VGA driver (such as when running in safe mode). You can check this in Device Manager. Try and get the actual video driver from the hardware manufacturer and update, it should then allow you to select any resolution supported by your hardware - whether or not 1920x1200 will be there is another question, but you will get common ones like 1280x1024.